# Visual studio Find and Replace with Regex does not use first match

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to convert all strings like:

```
return DeserializedHttpResponse<Workflow>.op_Implicit(...
return DeserializedHttpResponse<Stream>.op_Implicit(...
```

into

```
(Workflow)(...
(Stream)(...
```

using Visual Studio 2019 find and replace tool with regex enabled.

This is my Regex:

```
Find: DeserializedHttpResponse<.*>.op_Implicit

Replace with: ($1)
or
Replace with: (\1)
```

It correctly recognizes the input string. But it replaces them with:

```
($1)
or
(\1)
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. seems legit to me

Comment: `DeserializedHttpResponse<.*>.op_Implicit` > `DeserializedHttpResponse<([^<>]*)>.op_Implicit`. You did not specify a *capturing group*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It solved it, also I had to replace it with the first group `${1}`. Strange why it doesn't work with just **match**. If you care to post an answer I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: You do not need `${1}`, `$1` will work unless you add a digit after the backreference (but you have a `)` there). The only problem was missing capturing parentheses around the part you needed to keep.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, aaah I see. although `DeserializedHttpResponse<(.*)>.op_Implicit` works too

Comment: Yes, but it looks like the string inside `<...>` cannot contain `<` and `>` in this concrete case. It makes sense to restrict the pattern with a negated character class here, or at least use a `.*?` lazy dot instead of the greedy dot, then the regex won't overmatch in case of several matches on one line.